# When should you register/deregister for events/messages

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm-light

I am looking at events and messages in my application but am not sure on the lifecycle of them and when you should be registering for them.

At the moment in the constructor of the control I register to receive messages (or event handlers). I don't deregister though which I think is a mistake

For example in this posting: [MVVM Messaging vs RaisePropertyChanged<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982639/mvvm-messaging-vs-raisepropertychangedt/6324776#6324776) it says to deregister on the `Unloaded` event.

Hwever in my application I am using Telerik controls (it might happen in other controls) and I have a window within the main screen. When I undock the screen and at other times the `Unloaded` and `Loaded` events trigger even though the window itself doesn't seem to close.

So if I deregister in the `Unloaded` then it is going to cause an issue. So at what point should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, I unregister events as soon as I know they are no longer relevant, which can vary.  If unloaded is happening, and yet the window is staying then it makes sense that load is happening too (as you mentioned).  In that case perhaps you should register them in load, and unregister them in unload.  That should guarantee matching.  I do not see a better event than Unload you could use, if you need it for the lifespan of the userControl/page.

Comment: The problem I foresee in this is that in the split second that the events are deregistered it is possible one would be raised and missed.

Comment: I am not sure what is generating your event, but if its outside of that control you could register it outside and call a method inside.  If the item the event is part of is in that control/page then there shouldn't be any problems with them hanging around as they should be destroyed when the control is  (although I much prefer to unregister anything I register).  However all in all, that doesn't really answer your question :(

Comment: What sort of event are you registering?  Like what is it attached to?  I can't help but think that if its tied to something directly on your window/page/control that it couldn't fire while its loading again.  (a control for example)

Comment: It would be a message sent from an XMPP server, so it could fire whilst it's loading again unfortunately

Comment: I take back what I said before.  If the thing publishing the event for receiving from the XMPP server is alive when your window/control fully closes those event handlers are going to stay until that object goes out of scope and gets garbage collected.  Do you maintain a list of the existing open windows?  If so, I think you are going to have to move the registering and unregistering of the events to the methods that handle tracking the windows themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with [D..'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929784/when-should-you-register-deregister-for-events-messages/7929879#7929879) but there're some cases that Loaded and Unloaded event handler call more than once. I fix this problem by add bool variable to check before Register.

**Example code:**

```
bool _hasRegistered; // default value is false

OnLoaded()
{
    //
    if (!this._hasRegistered)
    {
        // your register code here
        this._hasRegistered = true;
    }
}

OnUnloaded()
{
    // your un-register code here
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Sometimes the simplest things escape me.